# Flex backkeypressedhandler not launching with states

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex4.5

I'm developping an mobile program with the Flex 4.5 SDK, this for my thesis for school. I have a bug in my program that I can't fix.

I have a view where I have 2 states. When I change from state my program doesn't listen to the backKey event anymore.
I allready tried this:

```
backKeyPressed.mystate = "backKeyPressed(event)"
```

But this doesn't help.
I made a small program to show you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Home"
    initialize="init()"
    backKeyPressed="view1_backKeyPressedHandler(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        [Bindable]
        private var m_list:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        private function init():void
        {

        }

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            currentState = 'state2';

        }

        protected function button2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            currentState = 'state1';

        }

        protected function view1_backKeyPressedHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            event.preventDefault();

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:State name="state1"/>
    <s:State name="state2"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Group id="stateOneGroup" includeIn="state1">
    <s:Button x="30" y="112" label="To State 2"
              click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <s:Label x="72" y="216" text="State1"/>
</s:Group>

<s:Group id="stateTwoGroup" includeIn="state2">
    <s:Button x="267" y="112" label="To State 1"
              click="button2_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <s:Label x="303" y="216" text="State2"/>
</s:Group>

 </s:View>
```

I also searched on adobe if it's a bug but I don't seem to find it.

I hope someone can help me.

Kind regards,

Thibault Heylen

Comment: According to the code you provided above it looks like the back button won't ever do anything since you call preventDefault() on it.  This is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues today. At last i got it. In my issues, if it is the first view, the backkeypressed doesn't work, but for the other views, the backkeypressed works well.

Hope this helps